# single-row subquery returns more than one row error. Is it my script or my return data?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help on creating updating SQL script

**TableA**

```
colA    colB    colC    colD    colE
  a       b       x       g       z 
  b       c       d       g       h 
  c       d       f       g       v  
  v       f       f       g       f
  d       a       q       o       a
```

**TableB**

```
colA    colB    colC    colD    colE
  a       b       x       y       a 
  b       c       d       g       b 
  c       d       f       g       c  
  d       e       s       g       d
  v       f       f       g       e
```

I need TableB.colE to update to TableA.colE where TableB.colD = TableA.colD
Result shall be

**TableA**

```
colA    colB    colC    colD    colE
  a       b       x       g       b 
  b       c       d       g       c 
  c       d       f       g       d  
  v       f       f       g       e
  d       a       q       o       a
```

I have tried using

```
UPDATE TABLEA SET(TABLEA.COLE=TABLEB.COLE) WHERE TABLEA.COLD =  TABLEB.COLD
```

it doesn't work.

Comment: but in this case your TABLEA.COLD should be same or what is the uniqe key in both tables..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UPDATE TABLEA SET TABLEA.COLE=TABLEB.COLE from TABLEB WHERE TABLEA.COLD =  TABLEB.COLD`

You have missed to specify the second table name TABLEB in from clause. Try this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this update:

```
UPDATE TableA a
   SET COLE = ( SELECT COLE
                FROM TableB b
                WHERE b.COLD = a.COLD );
```

Comment: I will get this error if I use your SQL
single-row subquery returns more than one row error

Comment: Can you use ColB in condition? I think it's better way.

Comment: No ColB is not to be condition.

Comment: How do we know we have to update 1st row with `a` value, not `d`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the table join in the first clause of the update

```
UPDATE
(
  SELECT tablea.cole, tableb.cole as newvalue
    FROM tablea
    JOIN tableb
      ON tablea.cold = tableb.cold
)
SET cole = newvalue
```

Comment: Tried yours but getting this error - ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table

Comment: my TABLEB is a vm table. could it be a problem?